# Is there a software package to fit grouped (aggregated) logistic panel regression models?

Tags: regression, logistic, panel-data, aggregation

I have a dataset that looks like the following

```
id | time | trial  | success | other covariates 
1    0  10    4    
1    1  23    10     
1    2  100   29     
2    0  5     1
```

etc

this is basically a panel aggregated logistic regression. 
Can someone point me towards a package I can use for grouped logistic PANEL regression? 
I am aware of PGLM package in R
I tried to use stata with xtlogit but it wouldn't take grouped logistic with fweight options. 
What I am looking for is something like blogit in stata but something that can take panel data. I'd presume the function would be called xtblogit but it doesn't exist.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by panel and aggregated in this context? Or even better, provide some data that works in R or Stata but for which you're not quite getting the result you want. I'm thinking that what you're looking for in R is a glmm with id as a random effect and the 2 column response, but your terminology is making it hard to see if that's true.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reasonably recent version of Stata (version 10, released 2007, or above) you can use the `xtmelogit` command. While `xtlogit` fits only a random intercept, `xtmelogit` allows you to specify more random effects. Depending on your model, you may or may not want to make use of that. But `xtmelogit` also has a `binomial(varname)`option that allows for grouped binomial data of the form you have.

Alternatively, if the random-intercept model is sufficient and you prefer to use `xtlogit` with its somewhat simpler syntax, you could convert your data into the form it wants by 'de-aggregating' it. Joseph Hilbe wrote an `unblock` command ages ago to make that easier: type `findit unblock` to install it.

Comment: thank you for the help
i also found gllamm and denom() option is also useful